# Expo React Native Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: react-native, expo

I started getting this error today

> Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen
> if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

I read in this thread [Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered While running react-native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543844/invariant-violation-main-has-not-been-registered-while-running-react-native-a/67550379) that might be because i have multiple versions of react native safe area content.

I ran npm why react-native-safe-area-content and this is what i got

> react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
> node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
> react-native-safe-area-context@"4.2.4" from the root project   peer
> react-native-safe-area-context@">= 3.0.0" from
> @react-navigation/elements@1.3.3
> node_modules/@react-navigation/elements
> @react-navigation/elements@"^1.3.3" from @react-navigation/native-stack@6.6.2
> node_modules/@react-navigation/native-stack
> @react-navigation/native-stack@"^6.6.2" from the root project
> @react-navigation/elements@"^1.3.3" from @react-navigation/stack@6.2.1
> node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
> @react-navigation/stack@"^6.2.1" from the root project   peer react-native-safe-area-context@">= 3.0.0" from
> @react-navigation/native-stack@6.6.2
> node_modules/@react-navigation/native-stack
> @react-navigation/native-stack@"^6.6.2" from the root project   peer react-native-safe-area-context@">= 3.0.0" from
> @react-navigation/stack@6.2.1   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
> @react-navigation/stack@"^6.2.1" from the root project

But i don't know what to do now, how should i proceed?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue

Comment: Nop, i just started another project hahaha

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the version of the `react-native-safe-area-context` in my `package.json` was different from the one used in a dependency. The solution was to use the same version the dependency was using.

My `package.json` had `4.3.1` while my dependency (react-native-gifted-chat) had `4.4.1`, a higher version.

To figure out the versions I used `yarn why react-native-safe-area-context`.

```
$ yarn why react-native-safe-area-context
yarn why v1.22.19
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "react-native-safe-area-context"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.1"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "_project_#expo-app" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#expo-app#react-native-safe-area-context"
info Disk size without dependencies: "1016KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1016KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "1016KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 0
=> Found "react-native-gifted-chat#react-native-safe-area-context@4.4.1"
info This module exists because "_project_#expo-app#react-native-gifted-chat" depends on it.
info Disk size without dependencies: "968KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "968KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "968KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 0
✨  Done in 0.94s.
```

To match the versions I installed the specific version using the command below

```
yarn add react-native-safe-area-context@4.4.1
```